# I am trying to create a base class for Apple Pay payment processing

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, applepay

I have created a base class for Apple Pay functionality. But that base class is inherited by NSObject . I have created the payment authorise viewcontroller with in this class only and assigned it’s delegate to self. Now it’s not invoking the delegate methods of pkpaymentauthorizationviewcontrollerdelegate. How can I fix this situation and implement delegate method just once in base class and reuse it else where in application. Please help.

```
class ApplePay: NSObject { 
 
var applePayItem: PKPaymentSummaryItem?
var baseVC: UIViewController?
let payNetworks = [PKPaymentNetwork.masterCard, .visa, .amex, .discover]


init(forItem: Product) {
    applePayItem = PKPaymentSummaryItem.init(label: forItem.name ?? "",
                                             amount: NSDecimalNumber(value: forItem.price ?? 0))
}

func initiatePayment(complete: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
    if PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController.canMakePayments(usingNetworks: payNetworks) {
        let request = PKPaymentRequest()
            request.currencyCode = "USD"
            request.countryCode = "US"
            request.merchantIdentifier = <*identifier from my development account*>
            request.merchantCapabilities = PKMerchantCapability.capability3DS
            request.supportedNetworks = payNetworks
            request.paymentSummaryItems = [applePayItem!]
        guard let paymentVC = PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController(paymentRequest: request) else {
            return
        }
        baseVC = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.children.last
        baseVC?.present(paymentVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
        paymentVC.delegate = self
        complete(true)
    } else {
        complete(false)
        CaAssembly.resolve(CaAlertProtocol.self)!.showAlert(CaConstant.alertTitles.addCardApplePay, dismiss: {})
    }
}

func paymentAuthorizationControllerDidFinish(_ controller: PKPaymentAuthorizationController) {
    controller.dismiss {
        
}
func paymentAuthorizationViewControllerDidFinish(_ controller: PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController) {
    controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}



 }

 extension ApplePay: PKPaymentAuthorizationViewControllerDelegate, 
PKPaymentAuthorizationControllerDelegate {
 @available(iOS 11.0, *)
 func paymentAuthorizationViewController(_ controller: 
   PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController, 
   didAuthorizePayment payment: PKPayment, 
   handler completion: @escaping 
  (PKPaymentAuthorizationResult) -> Void) {
    print(“PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController didAuthorizePayment” )
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you share what you've tried and what you expect is causing the unexpected functionality?

Comment: For thee time being I am thinking of making ApplePay class back to inheriting UIViewController and making its background transparent, then calling to present Apple Pay authorise VC on viewdidappear.... if that works then it will be fine for me.

Comment: Just for the update ... I was able to implement it by UIViewController inherited base class ... using library [https://github.com/IcaliaLabs/Presentr] using which I presented base class as modal with dimensions (w:0,h:0) and initiated Apple Pay on its viewdidappear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for the update ... I was able to implement it by UIViewController inherited base class ... using library [github.com/IcaliaLabs/Presentr] using which I presented base class as modal with dimensions (w:0,h:0) and initiated Apple Pay on its viewdidappear  :

```
import UIKit
import PassKit
import Alamofire
import Presentr

struct Product {
   var name: String
   var price: Double
}

class ApplePay: UIViewController , PKPaymentAuthorizationControllerDelegate, 
PKPaymentAuthorizationViewControllerDelegate{ //
 
var applePayItem: PKPaymentSummaryItem?
let output = ""
var baseVC: UIViewController?
let payNetworks = [PKPaymentNetwork.masterCard, .visa, .amex, .discover]
var presenter: Presentr = {
    let customPresenter = Presentr(
        presentationType: .custom(
            width: ModalSize.custom(size: 0),
            height: ModalSize.custom(size: 0),
            center: ModalCenterPosition.bottomCenter
        )
    )
    customPresenter.keyboardTranslationType = .compress
    return customPresenter
}()
var forItem: Product?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    applePayItem = PKPaymentSummaryItem.init(label: forItem?.name ?? "",
                                             amount: NSDecimalNumber(value: forItem?.price ?? 0))
}
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    initiatePayment()
}
func initiatePayment() {
    if PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController.canMakePayments(usingNetworks: payNetworks) {
        let request = PKPaymentRequest()
            request.currencyCode = "USD"
            request.countryCode = "US"
            request.merchantIdentifier = <merchant id created on developer account>
            request.merchantCapabilities = PKMerchantCapability.capability3DS
            request.supportedNetworks = payNetworks
            request.paymentSummaryItems = [applePayItem!]
        guard let paymentVC = PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController(paymentRequest: request) else {
            return
        }
        self.present(paymentVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
        paymentVC.delegate = self
    } 
}

func paymentAuthorizationControllerDidFinish(_ controller: PKPaymentAuthorizationController) {
    controller.dismiss {
        
    }
}
func paymentAuthorizationViewControllerDidFinish(_ controller: PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController) {
    controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

@available(iOS 11.0, *)
func paymentAuthorizationViewController(_ controller: PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController, didAuthorizePayment payment: PKPayment, handler completion: @escaping (PKPaymentAuthorizationResult) -> Void) {
    
}

}
```